# Subscription to data increases by 1 each time component loads

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-observable

I have the following method in the service to register data with `BehaviourSubject`.

```js
regFieldsModules(fieldsModules?, field?: Field) {

  // Using the previously stored data from the memory
  if (fieldsModules) {
    this.fieldMod = fieldsModules;
  }

  // Stop processing if fieldModules is null/ undefined
  if (!this.fieldMod) {
    return;
  }

  const groupFields = groupBy(this.fieldMod, 'id');
  const uniqueFields: Field[] = removeDuplicates(this.fieldMod, 'id');

  // Find the default field and assign it to the field
  if (uniqueFields && !field) {
    for (const f of uniqueFields) {
      if (f.isDefault) {
        field = f;
      }
    }

    this.fields.next(uniqueFields);
  }

  this.field.next(field);
  this.fieldModules.next(groupFields[field.id]);
}
```

And using it in the component as:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.dataService.fields.subscribe(fields => {
      if (!fields) {
        return;
      }

      for (const f of fields) {
        if (+params['id'] === f.id) {
          this.field = f;
          this.dataService.regFieldsModules(null, this.field);

          this.dataService.fieldModules.subscribe(data => {
            if (data) {
              console.log(data);
              this.groupedModules = groupBy(data, 'moduleId');
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The first time it console one time, and If I change route and visit the route again it prints two times, and third times it print third times... it continues. I cannot unsubscribe as the data changes and I need to subscribe for it.

This might resolve if I unsubscribe all subscriptions on destroy but I have another user case:

I have drop down on the header. On the selection, the parameter changes and the component refreshes. In this case the `OnDestroy` method is not called.

And is there a better way to write the above code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must unsubscribe from all subscriptions to external services everytime a component is destroyed, or you will be creating a memory leak in your application, you're also creating a leak by using nested subscriptions instead of higher order operators. this is how to do it correctly:

```
this.sub = combineLatest(this.route.params, this.dataService.fields) // combine subscriptions that don't rely on eachother
             .pipe(
               switchMap(([params, fields]) => { //switchMap into new observables to auto cancel previous subscriptions on new emissions
                 if (!fields) {
                   return EMPTY; // return empty to not emit in the no fields case
                 }

                 const field = fields.find(f => +params['id'] === f.id); // find instead of looping

                 this.field = field; // this block is problematic. Why are you creating side effects here? 
                 this.dataService.regFieldsModules(null, this.field); 

                 return this.dataService.fieldModules; // why switch into a new observable after calling that method?
               })
             ).subscribe(data => { // now I've got the data
               if (data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  this.groupedModules = groupBy(data, 'moduleId');
                }
             });
```

then in ngOnDestroy run:

```
this.sub.unsubscribe();
```